# How to use Robot Framework Scripts for Load Testing or performance testing

Tags: selenium, jmeter, robotframework

I have python scripts which are based on Robot Framework and were generally developed for Functional Testing. How can I achieve the Load Testing?
How to approach this problem? should I use Jmeter in order to run load testing (if yes then how is it possible) or there are some other methods available?

Answer (score 1):

If you're a programmer and your team has a good culture of software and code review.

Instead of Jmeter, you have another choice **Taurus**

Taurus can consume configuration files written in JSON or YAML. But it also supports Jmeter.

It will be easier for code review and construct your own load test.

Some material you can read:

YAMLTutorial:

https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/

Automating Performance Tests with Taurus:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DN0VNnG-lzs

Simple load test example with Taurus:
https://medium.com/@s6307/how-to-design-a-good-load-test-with-jmeter-and-taurus-like-a-pro-part-1-1d1b32fd77be

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using rfswarm, as it's designed exactly for this purpose:

https://github.com/damies13/rfswarm/blob/master/README.md

In the documentation there is even some details about things to consider when adjusting your robot files for use in performance testing.

Good luck with your project and i hope this answer is not too late for you.

Dave.